# Check os platform programmatically in Cordova ?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I need to run a set of code if the platform is ios only i am building the app for ios,android and i use AngularJS, How could i check whether the app running in ios or android in angular controller?

Comment: This may help https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

Comment: Thanks this what am looking :)